# Conditionally concatenate two string columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace duplicates with the dict below nth. I'm wondering how I am able to ignore certain values so they aren't replaced. For example if the name 'Jack' comes up don't change it to 'firstJack' just leave it as 'Jack'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nth = {
    0: 'first',
    1: 'second',
    2: 'third',
    3: 'fourth'}
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Tom', 'Jack', 'Terry'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.Name = df.groupby('Name').cumcount().map(nth) + df.Name
print(df)
```

Comment: Use `df.loc[~df['name'].isin(ignore_list)]...` before you groupby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a condition on the `groupby` output so you add no prefix if the row matches your condition.

```
to_ignore = ['Jack']
(np.where(df['Name'].isin(to_ignore), '', df.groupby('Name').cumcount().map(nth)) 
 + df['Name'])

0      firstTom
1     secondTom
2          Jack
3    firstTerry
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you! I do have a follow up question please see edit.

Comment: @Logan0015 Just need to play around with the first argument of `np.where` (the condition), You probably want `(df['Name'].isin(['Tom']) & df['Age'].eq(21))` or something similar. Encourage you to play around with the code :)

Comment: Do I just add the age condition at the end like this? `df['Name'] = (np.where(df['Name'].isin(['Tom']) & df['Age'].eq(21)), df.groupby('Name').cumcount().map(nth))`

Comment: @Logan0015 `(np.where(df['Name'].isin(to_ignore) & df['Age'].eq(21), '', df.groupby('Name').cumcount().map(nth)) 
 + df['Name'])`

Comment: Thank you. It does run, but the value for the age doesn't seem to have any impact on the output.